# multipart/form-data vazio (ASPNET CORE)

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando fazer o envio de arquivos para minha api via 'POSTMAN', mas quando a requisição chega no endpoint da API o 'IFormFile' sempre vem vazio.

POSTMAN

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous] //utilizada apenas para teste - alterar para as roles
[HttpPost("UploadFile")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    var teste2 = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files //-> null
    var teste file; //-> null
    var path = Path.GetTempFileName();

    return Ok();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, a key, no postman, precisa ter o mesmo nome do parâmetro, no caso `file`.

Comment: era isso mesmo, me salvou cara vlw